# Convert Subquery SQL to Laravel possible?

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb

Is this possible to change this SQL to let it work on Laravel?

```
SELECT  name, event,m.season_id, tm.played_pugs, active, m.created_at, datediff(now(),m.created_at)
FROM matchs m
LEFT OUTER JOIN seasons ON seasons.id = m.season_id
JOIN ( SELECT season_id, max(matchs.created_at) as MaxDate, count(season_id) as played_pugs
                  FROM matchs
                  GROUP BY season_id) tm on m.season_id = tm.season_id and m.created_at = tm.MaxDate
ORDER BY played_pugs descc>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$seasons = DB::table('matchs')
    ->select('name', 'event', 'season_id', 'played_pugs', 'active', DB::raw('datediff(now(),created_at) as days'))
    ->join('seasons', 'seasons.id', '=', 'matchs.season_id', 'left outer')
    ->join(DB::raw('SELECT season_id, max(matchs.created_at) as MaxDate, count(season_id) as played_pugs FROM matchs GROUP BY season_id)'), '')
    ->orderBy('played_pugs','desc')
    ->get();
```

Also I can't see the values with 'played_pugs' that have value 0 anymore. How can I fix that.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Try reading the [Laravel Query Builder Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries) to get you started and if you can't get it to work post what you've done so far here.

Comment: `$seasons = DB::table('matchs')
                       ->select('name', 'event', 'season_id', 'played_pugs', 'active', DB::raw('datediff(now(),created_at) as days'))
                      ->join('seasons', 'seasons.id', '=', 'matchs.season_id', 'left outer')
                      ->join(DB::raw('SELECT season_id, max(matchs.created_at) as MaxDate, count(season_id) as played_pugs
                     FROM matchs
                     GROUP BY season_id)'), '')
                        ->orderBy('played_pugs','desc')
                         ->get();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will generate the exact query you posted. I've built the join subquery using a separate Query Builder object and used the `toSql()` method to get the generated SQL string to inject using `DB::raw()`, because it's more readable this way and it's 100% built using the Query Builder syntax.

```php
$joinSubquery = DB::table('matchs')
    ->select('season_id', DB::raw('max(matchs.created_at) as MaxDate'), DB::raw('count(season_id) as played_pugs'))
    ->groupBy('season_id')
    ->toSql();

$seasons = DB::table('matchs m')
    ->select('name', 'event', 'm.season_id', 'tm.played_pugs', 'active', 'm.created_at', DB::raw('datediff(now(), m.created_at)'))
    ->leftJoin('seasons', 'season.id', '=', 'm.season_id', '')
    ->join(DB::raw('(' . $joinSubquery . ') tm'), function ($join)
    {
        $join->on('m.season_id', '=', 'tm.season_id');
        $join->on('m.created_at', '=', 'tm.MaxDate');
    })
    ->orderBy('played_pugs', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can I assign the M and TM (M = from matchs) and the TM (the subquery). When I use your query I got the following problem SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ebotv3.matchs m' doesn't exist (SQL: select `name`, ..

Comment: The error says the table is not found in the database, it doesn't mean the query is incorrect. Is the table name correctly spelled `matchs`?

Comment: Yes the table is called `matchs`

Think he sees it as `matchs m` instead of `matchs`.

Comment: Fixed it Thanks for it! +1 It seems that I need to added the AS function to matchs. This is the best way I assume to use subqueries.

Comment: (snide remark)  Does Laravel make it easier to write SQL?